# Cin reading until ';' is found in cpp

Tags: c++, input, stream

I am reading some numbers. The input is for example:

```
1 2 3 4 ; 2 3 4 5 6;
```

When I read ';' I want to do something with it and the number up to it. Currently, I am using:

```
while(1) {
    cin >> num;
    if(cin.fail()){
        // end of first array
        return 0;
    }
}
```

However, this way cin may fail if it is any char, not just ';'

Comment: [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) along with `std::istringstream` will let you do what you want

Comment: If `std::cin` is in fail state the next character to read will be a `';'` in your example, and you can use `clear()` and consume the `';' character to continue`.

Comment: Take a look at option 2 in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7868998/4581301 . Take advantage of the ability to specify the  end of line token (`while (std::getline(infile, line, ';'))`) and replace the file stream with `cin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read cahr and check it. If it isn't a digit, do what you want and return; else put the char back using `cin.putback(char)` and read int.

```
 char c;
 while (1) {
     cin >> c;
     if (c < '0' || c >'9') { // is not digit
         // do something
         return 0;
     }
     cin.putback(c);
     cin >> num;
 }
```